# I want the iPhone keyboard to dismiss with the current view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikeyboard

Use the slide gesture to pop a view controller, and the keyboard disappears after the view controller disappears.

I want it to disappear together with the view controller like iPhone Message's keyboard.

Comment: have you tried the answer provided to this question?  I think it is what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984224/animate-the-keyboard-in-sync-with-the-uiview-while-edge-swiping-back-in-ios7

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually hide the keyboard by calling `resignFirstResponder` on your textfields or whatever it is you are using to get keyboard input.

Or you can use `[self.view endEditing:YES];`

Whichever one you choose, you can run it in the viewWillDisappear, that way the keyboard will dismiss along with the view. For example:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.view endEditing:YES]; //Hides keyboard
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: you open your iphone message. let the keyboard appear.and slide back slowly .i want that