# Why keyboard hides when I apply custom push animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-transition

I have two controllers with UITextFields on them. I need a custom transition between them with the keyboard shown, alongside transition.

When I'm using the default push animation, everything is good. But if I return my transition class from `animationControllerForOperation`, the keyboard is hiding before and showing after the transition.

So, could someone suggest to me a solution or explanation, why the keyboard is hiding with the custom transition?  Transition duration = 0.4, I've set `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` in `viewDidLoad`.

Here is a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gs16tMsU4qY

Comment: Could you show your transition animation code? Also, is the hide/show really so bad? I barely noticed it, myself.

Comment: I don't see a reason in your example to even use multiple view controllers for what you're trying to accomplish. That can easily be handled by animating the textField itself to change content without moving controllers in and out. Keeping a keyboard open while changing controllers seems confusing IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator class.

Here is the answer to the similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21017900

Comment: `animateAlongsideTransition` is performed only for push for some reason, keyboard view completely ignoring my changes of it's frame, when I return my own `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` from `animationControllerForOperation`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Or even an easier way:

implementing the delegate method `- (BOOL) textFieldShouldEndEditing: (UITextField*) textField`of `UITextField` and returning NO as long as the next VC is not loaded yet...

---

Perhaps you could try to override `- (BOOL) canResignFirstResponder`method of `UITextField` to return `NO` as long as the view of the new view controller is not loaded yet. (by setting a `BOOL` property for example, that is set to `YES` when the new view controller's view is loaded). like:

```
- (BOOL) canResignFirstResponder {
    return nextVCIsLoaded;
}
```

perhaps that might prevent the keyboard from being hidden (that seems to happen automatically somewhere within the 'push' operation).

Hope this approach helps.